# Is it possible to access different fragments in one bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Is it possible to access different fragments in one bottom navigation view? Because  what I'm trying to do is something like this.

```
if(db=00){
   //go to fragment 1
}else{
//go to fragment 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FragmentManager and FragmentTransactions to change fragments in your layouts!

```
Fragment frag = new Fragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentTransaction().replace(R.id.containerViewId, yourFragment).commit()
```

Comment: what does getFragmentTransaction do?

Comment: Front Developer.android.com - “API for performing a set of fragment operations”, this is what it says for the replace method - “Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as called remove(fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added to the container with that Id and then add(int, fragment, tag) with the same arguments given here”